# How do I edit a masked image?

Tags: python, image, opencv

How do ı make the image I've masked smoother? I want to remove the little white pixels from the second picture, and I want to throw some of the masked places out of the picture, how can I do that?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("colors.jpg")
height,width = 720,720
img = cv2.resize(img,(width,height))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([100,50,50])
upper_range = np.array([150,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
#res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.imshow("Mask",mask)
#cv2.imshow("res",res)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

[image: My image]

[image: My result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the closing and opening concept of computer vision. You need is erosion in your case to get rid of the tiny white dots.

There are two things that can controlled for the resultant outcome as per your requirement i.e. `kernel size` and `iterations`.

Here is the code is I could reproduce and provide a near solution.

```
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("colors.jpg")
height,width = 720,720
img = cv2.resize(img,(width,height))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([100,50,50])
upper_range = np.array([150,255,255])
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
erosion = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)
#res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)


cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.imshow("Mask",erosion)
#cv2.imshow("res",res)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
import cv2
import numpy as np
​
img = cv2.imread("colors.jpg")
height,width = 720,720
img = cv2.resize(img,(width,height))
​
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
​
lower_range = np.array([100,50,50])
upper_range = np.array([150,255,255])
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
erosion = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)
#res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)
​
​
cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.imshow("Mask",erosion)
#cv2.imshow("res",res)
​
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Result:

[image: resultant image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I only have one problem: if I want to throw away the white part at the bottom, can I throw it away or do I have to change the range?

Comment: The question is not understandable. At the bottom? you can crop the image instead using CV.

Comment: Is there a way to remove any one of these white box of pixels?